# Zsh: Behaviour of zargs with empty list - ist this a bug or a feature?

Tags: zsh

I stumbled today over the following problem in zsh 5.1.1 (simplified example):

```
#!/bin/zsh
autoload -U zargs
zargs -- my*files(N) -- rm -v
```

This worked fine, until one day, there were no files matching my pattern. Because of the `(N)`, the command turned into

```
zargs -- -- rm -v
```

I had expected, that in this case `rm` would not be called at all, in a similar vain where `xargs` does not call the command if the imput is empty. However, `rm` **was** called once, without arguments, which then had the effect that an error message was written.

Indeed, we can see that

```
zargs -- -- echo xxx
```

also invokes `echo` once.

The documentation of `zargs` in the man page is not really clear in this respects, but I think that without arguments, the command should not be invoked at all.

Do we have a bug, or is `zargs` really supposed to work in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zargs` works in this way similar to GNU `xargs` today (ugh...).

We could use the `-r, --no-run-if-empty` option.
`zargs` inherits this property from GNU `xargs`, from `zargs --help`:

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty        if there are no arguments, then do not run COMMAND;
                             if this option is not given, COMMAND will be
                             run at least once
```

GNU `xargs` has this *feature*:

> -r, --no-run-if-empty
>   If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the
>   command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.
>   This option is a GNU extension.
>   --[`xargs.1` nroff source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/xargs/xargs.1?id=v4.6.0#n270)

(Un?)fortunately, FreeBSD and [NetBSD's](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?xargs+1+NetBSD-current) have the counter feature like this:

> -r
>          Compatibility with GNU xargs.  The GNU version of xargs runs the
>            utility argument at least once, even if xargs input is empty, and
>            it supports a -r option to inhibit this behavior.  The FreeBSD
>            version of xargs does not run the utility argument on empty
>            input, but it supports the -r option for command-line compatibility
>            with GNU xargs, but the -r option does nothing in the FreeBSD
>            version of xargs.
>   --[`FreeBSD xargs(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&sektion=1)